# Multiple Joins In Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, ssms

I am writing a query that brings in period from another table, so if this year then period is 201901 - 201912 next year = 202001 - 202012 and last year is 201801 - 201812 this is the financial period.

Currently the GL period table shows 201903 i.e. June 2018. I want to write a query so I can get this year next and last year dates my join can only return ONE i.e. either this year or next year or last year, however I want it to return all three. How do I do this?

```
SELECT 
yearfrom,
period,
fld_from,
fld_to,
fld_desc,
[ThisYear] = ((select(LEFT(Gl_GLPARAM.PERIOD,4)) from Gl_GLPARAM)),
[LastYear] = ((select(LEFT(Gl_GLPARAM.PERIOD,4))-1 from Gl_GLPARAM)),
[NextYear] = ((select(LEFT(Gl_GLPARAM.PERIOD,4))+1 from Gl_GLPARAM))


FROM GL_YEARPDET
right join (select(LEFT(Gl_GLPARAM.PERIOD,4)) as 'ThisYear' from Gl_GLPARAM) 
as T1 on GL_YEARPDET.YearFrom = t1.ThisYear
```

I need this same as above somehow added to the subquery

```
right join (select(LEFT(Gl_GLPARAM.PERIOD,4))+1 as 'NextYear' from 
Gl_GLPARAM) as T2 on GL_YEARPDET.YearFrom = t2.NextYear
right join (select(LEFT(Gl_GLPARAM.PERIOD,4))+1 as 'LastYear' from 
Gl_GLPARAM) as T3 on GL_YEARPDET.YearFrom = t3.LastYear
```

[SqlSubqueryresult](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaVrs.png)

[SampleTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNpMY.png)

Comment: It's extremely helpful if you add a tag for the DBMS you're using, as functionality and syntax between them differs. (And please don't SHOUT when asking questions here. It won't get you help any faster and it makes the text harder to read. Please use your Shift key instead of your CAPS LOCK. Thanks.)

Comment: Sorry dbms is ssms i was not shouting, only caps is 'one' which is emphasis shout is if you cap a sentence. some words in query is in caps because thats how i write them, its easier to read.

Comment: I was referring to the title  of your post. If you look at the list of questions on the main page, none of them is in ALL CAPS. There's a reason for that, which I described in my previous comment. You don't need to SHOUT FOR EMPHASIS when writing your title. It comes across as being very rude when you SHOUT, DEMANDING HELP here.

Comment: I know what you mean, but I cant see it lol title read's 'Multiple Joins in Sub Query' caps are only the first letter. can you post a screenshot, i am new to this forum and won't want to make the same mistake again.

Comment: I edited your post to remove the ALL CAPS title and make it proper cased. You can see the changes I made in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51276395/revisions). You don't know what you typed on your own keyboard? And you still have not edited to add that DBMS tag.

Comment: ahh yes ok sorry mate, I will add tags now as well :) noted and won't happen again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 FROM GL_YEARPDET
 where YearFrom IN( ((select(LEFT(Gl_GLPARAM.PERIOD,4)) from Gl_GLPARAM)), 
 ((select(LEFT(Gl_GLPARAM.PERIOD,4))-1 from Gl_GLPARAM)), 
 ((select(LEFT(Gl_GLPARAM.PERIOD,4))+1 from Gl_GLPARAM)))
```

where clause has fixed my issue.